# How can i get the usage statics programatically in android?

Tags: android

Explanation: I have working in an application. My client want the usage statics of all the installed application.I have read lot of blogs. I learnt a new thing for the usage API from the SDK version 25(Lollipop). There is some application on google play store namely Quick time. Which get all the information of the each and every applications with how many time application is used? How long user have been using the application? Last time used time every information.

I want an application like this so, I got last time but i don't know how to get the rest of the other question's answer's.

Please, help me solve out this problem..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try [fabric.io](https://fabric.io/home)

Comment: fabric, firebase analytics, google analytics or facebook analytics to name a few. Even the Google Play Developer consoler will give you some information about app usage.

Comment: Please follow this, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html

Comment: I want to start based on it.

Comment: I couldn't tried yet but if it require to i will try on it.